# Optimizing a set of rules to better predict the outcome of events

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to better predict the top three finishers of the next 1000 800m mens freestyle swimming race.

I've got a set of rules to rate the swimmers:

1) Add 5 points if the swimmer won his last race

2) Subtract 3 points if the swimmer is less than 6' tall

3) Add 10 points if the swimmer won his last two races

4) Add 3 points if the swimmer wears a full body swimming suit

5) Subtract 10 points if the swimmer's last race time was over 8 minutes

I want to optimize my set of rules so that the swimmer I rate the highest finishes first more often, the swimmer with the second highest rating finishes second (more often), and the swimmer with the third highest rating finishes third.

I can back-test over the last 5000 swimming races to optimize the rules.

For example, for a race on Jan1 2013 I have the following results:

swimmerID | rule1 | rule2 | rule3 | rule4 | rule5 | finalRating | finishPosition

Swimmer1  |  5    |  -3   |   0   |   3   |   0   |   5         |    1

Swimmer2  |  5    |  0   |   10   |   0   |   0   |   15        |    4

Swimmer3  |  5    |  0   |   0   |   3   |   3   |   11         |    3

Swimmer4  |  5    |  0   |   0   |   0   |   3   |   8         |    2

Swimmer5  |  5    |  -3   |   10   |   3   |   3   |   18        |    6

Swimmer6  |  5    |  -3   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   2         |    5

I can't figure out how to model this problem. I originally thought it was a simple lp problem but I couldn't get that to work.